# Displaying specific columns using SQL query

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table that contains more than 20 columns, but I only need information of 3 columns. How can i display just these 3 columns from the table using SQL query?

Comment: It probably took you longer to create an account here and ask this question than it would have to just google the syntax for an SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c 
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

When querying your table, you should specify which columns you wish to retrieve from.

```
SELECT [column1], [column2], [column3] FROM [tablename]
```

This is really basic.  I would recommend picking up an intro to SQL book or finding a guide online.

Comment: Are you sure that `Terradata` allow to quote identifiers with `[]`? I would say it is SQL Server/Sybase specific + compatibility in SQLite. The safer option would be `"`

Comment: I tried this using a 'AND' instead of ',' and it gave me a error. So, I thought I'm doing something wrong. And yes, I'm just starting to learn SQL. Thank you for answering.

Comment: I should have explained better.  Often times [item] is used to notify that [this block] should be replaced with what is inside... Such as `SELECT` apples, cats, dogs FROM myTable`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Col1
      ,Col2
      ,Col3
FROM Table_Name
```